# What is "diagonal" about this argument?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We  can show that $F: X \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ is injective but not surjective. The proof I read for the surjective case is as follows

Define the set

$$B = \{ c \in A: c \not \in F(c) \}$$

Now any $c \in A$. Then $c \in B$ if and only if $c \not \in F(c)$. Hence, $F(c) \neq B$, which means that $Y \not \in range(F)$. Hence, the function is not surjective.

Apparently, this is called Cantor's Diagonal Argument, which I am more familiar with in the context of proving that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. While it is quite clear what is "diagonal" in that argument, could someone please explain what is "diagonal" in this argument?

Comment: I think its just a term used - since the original argument was about a diagnolization, we calll the generalization of it diagnolization as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is finite, you can make a table with the $c\in A$ as row labels, and in that case order you can get the values of $F(c)$ as column labels. You can fill this table with truth values of statements of the form $c\in F(d)$. Deleting all rows and columns, except those for which $c\in B$, gives a table where the top left to bottom right diagonal is all false.

If $A$ is countably infinite, the same table can be visualized going on forever, down and to the right. And if $A$ is uncountable, we use the term "diagonal" as a geometric analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Ever play the game "Telephone," where you see how a sentence gets changed when repeated? This has happened to much of what appeared in Cantor's 1891 paper "Über eine elementare Frage der Mannigfaltigkeitslehre" (according to Babelfish, "About an elementary question of the doctrine of diversity.") It presented the formal proof you refer to, which in my experience is better known as [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) or Cantor's Power Set Theorem.

If I were to write a formal paper on, say, the Pythagorean Theorem, I might start with an informal example by constructing a right triangle with legs of length 3 and 4, and then showing that the hypotenuse has length 5. Well, Cantor started that paper such an informal example. It became what is widely known as [Cantor's Diagonal Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), Diagonal Method, Diagonal Argument, or Diagonal Slash.

Its purpose was to provide a more intuitive representation of what was to come later, the power sets. That proof applies to any set in the abstract, while the example was supposed to apply to a specific, easily-visualized set. About the only part of what is usually taught, that matches what Cantor wrote, is that it uses an actual diagonal. It was *explicitly* not applied to real numbers. It does not start with the assumption of a complete list. It is not really a proof-by-contradiction. What it proves, is that any infinite list of elements from the subject set is not a surjection. Then it argues (rather than proves) that a bijection is impossible.